# Android studio 3.3.2 пипетка для цвета

Tags: android-studio

Обновил студию до 3.3.2. Не могу понять, почему пипетка не работает для "взятия" цвета из других программ, как раньше. Только со своей палитры берёт. Кто знает в чем причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Причина в том, что это другая пипетка. Старая пипетка работает по прежнему по всему экрану (кроме панели задач), но спрятана глубоко в меню. Если пойти в File - Settings  и ввести в поле поиска Color Picker, то можно задать комбинацию клавиш для показа старой пипетки. Её можно и добавить на панель инструментов (File - Settings - Appearance & Behavior - Menus and Toolbars, выбрать куда, нажать Add after и найти в Other "Show Color Picker"), но добавление инструментов в АС сделано как-то криво и у меня еще ни разу не получилось.

Comment: Да, старая пипетка осталась. Всё верно. Добираюсь до неё без комбинаций Ctrl + Shift + A > Color Picker. Мне кажется, что это баг новой студии

Comment: Если часто нужна, то я бы поставил на нее что-нибудь вроде Ctrl + Alt + P.